# How to transcribe a list of DNA sequences to RNA in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

I am trying to return a list of RNA sequences transcribed from DNA sequences. Ideally it should look like:

```
DNA_seq = ['AGGTC','TTGACT','ATGGCA']
RNA_seq = ['UCCAG','AACUGA','UACCGU']
```

From my understanding, a dictionary should help store the key-value pairs for each nucleotide and its corresponding base pair. Here is what I have so far:

```
def RNA(DNA_strand):
    mapping = {'G':'C', 'C':'G', 'T':'A', 'A':'U'}
    rna_strand = ''
    for char in DNA_strand:
        rna_strand += mapping[char]
    return rna_strand
RNA_seq = []
for x in DNA_seq:
    RNA_seq.append(RNA(x))
```

I kind of pieced this together, but I still does not seem to be effective enough. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you are looking for. Your code does seem to run fine, so curious what the exact question is.

Comment: I apologize, there has seemed to be a problem with my IDE! When I first tried running this code there was an error, but I closed my program and reopened it which seemed to do the job!

Answer (score 3):

You could take advantage of `str.maketrans` to create your mapping, and then use `str.translate` to perform the substitution:

```
mapping = str.maketrans("GCTA", "CGAU")

for dna in "AGGTC", "TTGACT", "ATGGCA":
    print(dna.translate(mapping))
```

Output:

```
UCCAG
AACUGA
UACCGU
>>>
```

`str.maketrans` returns a dictionary of ordinal key-value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Mapping is definitely the right approach here. However, you can do all these tasks in one line without all the looping:

```
RNA_seq = ["".join([mapping[char] for char in DNA_strand]) for DNA_strand in DNA_seq]
```

Also this would be significantly more efficient as:

- it doesn't perform `str` concatenation for each character;
- list comp is faster than the respective for loop in this case, as it avoids the overhead of multiple `list.append()` calls.

Comment: A list comprehension doesn't eliminate the loop, and is not necessarily faster

Comment: It does the iteration at bytecode level, but it's faster in this case because it doesn't call append(). I'm afraid I phrased it as if they're *always* faster, which is not true.